# angular-cli installs but ng command is not recognized

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

It happens that when I install angular cli, it gets stuck at 
[this point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPgAb.png)

I have looked for any solution , install/uninstall node.js and tried to use different versions of node and npm with no success.

EDIT: After uninstalling node.js, erasing npm folder in appdata, and reinstalling again, it installs but it does not recognize the ng command as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlWhD.png)

Comment: can you install any other package?

Comment: Yes I can, now I'm trying to delete the npm and npm cache folder. It might work... now the problem is that the deleting lasts a lot

Comment: Now it installs but it doesn't recognize the ng command, going to edit the post for this.

Comment: The last time you didn't pass the `--global (-g)` option.

Comment: Please paste text instead of pointing us to pictures.

Comment: Have you correctly added the path to your npm directory to your global variable path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is a path issue. This solution helped me fix it on macOs High Sierra.

- npm install -g @angular/cli
- Make sure the ng path is correct
- cd ~/npm-global/bin
- ls and make sure ng exists
- create .bashrc file on your home directory
- touch ~/.bashrc
- vim ~/.bashrc
- Add ng as alias
- press i (enables edit mode) then type in the following
- alias ng="~/npm-global/bin/ng" (or wherever your ng directory is)
- press esc (to get out of edit mode) then :wq (in vim will save)
- Temporarily Update .bashrc reference
- Your terminal wont take bash updates until a restart but the following command will let you use the updates during the terminal session:
- source ~/.bashrc
  Check that ng works

ng --version

Found it from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5021

Comment: Npm version : 5.6.0, Node version :8.11.1, Angular CLI:  6.0.7

Answer (score 0):

May be try using `ng` commands with `node.js cli` (Node.js command prompt). It might work. I'd the same problem [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254127/ive-installed-angular-cli-but-its-showing-not-recognized-in-cmd).

Answer (score 0):

It happens that your node.js and angular visions are not compatible.

After the install and remove all the node files from on your pc. 
then try these commands.

1. Install node.js package manager stable version.
2. After the install you run `npm install`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli 04 ng new <project name>`
4. `cd <your project location>`
5. `ng serve`
   (If it's still not working, again `npm install` and `ng serve`)

If this is still not working, provide a sample of the .json file in your question.