# I've installed angular cli but its showing not recognized in cmd

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, git, npm

Actually I've installed `Nodejs`, then `npm`, then `angular cli` properly (afaik). But in windows cmd and in git bash, its showing "ng --version" as:

> `ng` is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

from windows command prompt

[image: from windows command prompt]

from github bash

[image: from github bash]

but when i try this command with node command prompt, it showing the ng version.

[image: from nodejs cli]

Because of this, i cannot use ng serve. Also i've tried to install bower and gulp. Getting the same "not recognised" error for both of them. Help to solve this.

Thanks and Regards,
sharfudeen

Comment: `> npm bin` and can you paste the `o/p`

Comment: C:\Users\User\node_modules\.bin

Comment: Now add this path to your environment or System environment path. All commands will start working.

Comment: let me try and post the answer.

Comment: where u install angular - globally or locally on a specific location. if it's specific location can u please navigate to project directory and try the command npm ng --version

Comment: @Priya, I've done the thing you've suggested. Still i'm getting the same error. check i've followed it properly? : http://imgur.com/hnwXWiV
http://imgur.com/dNt8Q7L

Comment: @JEMI I've installed it globally! Also i've navigated to my project folder, and getting the same error: http://imgur.com/nSBFIYe

Comment: are u trying the command from your project directory?

Comment: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli`
`npm cache clean`
`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
Run these commands and paste the screenshot. the ng command may be installed somewhere else which should be under your environment path.

Comment: I hope you installed node.js

Comment: @Priya i'll try. 
JEMI YES, i've installed node.js

Comment: yep @Priya its working fine when I re-install nodejs. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all please ensure you have installed **Node.js** on your machine

If You have already installed Node.js your machine you can take the Node.js command prompt instead of windows command prompt

[image]

and then try the command `npm ng --version`

[image]

On windows prompt go to your project local directory(use command **cd projectdirectorypath**) and then use the same command **npm ng --version**

Comment: Hey man, its working on nodejs cli. here: http://imgur.com/Pg8rHxa so i've to use node cli only?

Comment: @RuD3B0y  install angular-cli locally and try the same command with npm.It's worked for me

Comment: let me try and post the answer.